# Looping the data in xslt 3.0 by streaming

Tags: xml, for-loop, xslt, streaming, xslt-3.0

I have a input file xml called offerings and I have the course xml both are in combined xml and the file should have all the titles that are in the course  xml . In this case the number of titles present in offerings xml is 3 i.e

- Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 1
- Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 3
- Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 5

but in Course xml there 6 Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data titles
So i need to loop in and show a validation that no matching lesson found. can anyone help in looping in Streaming mode.

Updated Source xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<FileAndCourses>
    <Maps>
        <Locations>
            <Location>
                <InternalValue>7070</InternalValue>
                <ExternalValue>Laval</ExternalValue>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <InternalValue>7000</InternalValue>
                <ExternalValue>TORSSC</ExternalValue>
            </Location>
        </Locations>
            <Rooms>
                <Room>
                    <InternalValue>LOCATION-6-3881</InternalValue>
                    <ExternalValue>Ottawa District Training Center</ExternalValue>
                </Room>
            </Rooms>  
            
    </Maps>
    <Instructors>
        <Instructor>
        <InstructorID>119417764</InstructorID>
        <WorkdayUserName>AXH4006</WorkdayUserName>
    </Instructor>
    </Instructors>
      <AllCourses
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
                <wd:Learning_Course>
            <wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2b24f4f5c40000</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">00151744</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:ID>
            </wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
            <wd:Learning_Course_Data>
                <wd:ID>00151744</wd:ID>
                <wd:Effective_Date>2014-10-04</wd:Effective_Date>
                <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                <wd:Course_Title>Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:Course_Title>
                <wd:Description>Designing Kitchens Part II</wd:Description>
                <wd:Course_Number>00151744</wd:Course_Number>
                <wd:Topic_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9d1f49654c8310154e239c7090fc0000</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Topic">Product Knowledge - US</wd:ID>
                </wd:Topic_Reference>
                <wd:Language_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da594226446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="User_Language_ID">en_US</wd:ID>
                </wd:Language_Reference>
                <wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>0</wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                <wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>0</wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                <wd:Waitlist_Capacity>0</wd:Waitlist_Capacity>
                <wd:Unlimited_Capacity>1</wd:Unlimited_Capacity>
                <wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                    <wd:Pricing_Enabled>0</wd:Pricing_Enabled>
                    <wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>0</wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>
                </wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                <wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f31be4fd5caa10001d7c625e27014929</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Time_Unit_ID">HOURS</wd:ID>
                </wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                <wd:Total_Course_Duration>18</wd:Total_Course_Duration>
                <wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>0</wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>
                <wd:Legacy_Course>1</wd:Legacy_Course>
                <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df56ab318140000</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">100735117</wd:ID>
                </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b7f5fd27bc071018bbed7a460ce30000</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">119417764</wd:ID>
                </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df57b8e81f30002</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">104034590</wd:ID>
                </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                <wd:All_Locations>0</wd:All_Locations>
                <wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>1</wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>
                <wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>0</wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>
                <wd:Disable_Express_Interest>1</wd:Disable_Express_Interest>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>1</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 1</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>2</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 2</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>3</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 3</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>4</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 4</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>5</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 5</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>6</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 6</wd:Title>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                        <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                    </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>7</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Media_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2b23247d3f0004</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">MEDIA-6-4195</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">MEDIA-6-4195</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Media_Reference>
                        <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Welcome to HDU Distance Learning</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                        <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                    </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                    <wd:Lesson_Order>8</wd:Lesson_Order>
                    <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>0</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                    <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                        <wd:Media_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">358e28e73d5d10109aef5b042fc20000</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">cninv000000000020562.zip</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">cninv000000000020562.zip</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Media_Reference>
                        <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Course Feedback HDUv3</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                        <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                    </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
            </wd:Learning_Course_Data>
        </wd:Learning_Course>
          <wd:Learning_Course>
              <wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2c78dc802e0001</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course_ID">00170024CA</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Course">Design Basics (Designer Training 4) - Virtual ILT</wd:ID>
              </wd:Learning_Blended_Course_Reference>
              <wd:Learning_Course_Data>
                  <wd:ID>00170024CA</wd:ID>
                  <wd:Effective_Date>2019-02-26</wd:Effective_Date>
                  <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                  <wd:Course_Title>Design Basics (Designer Training 4) - Virtual ILT</wd:Course_Title>
                  <wd:Description>&lt;p>In this 5 module virtual course the designer will learn the basics of drafting and laying out basic designs for Contractors and DIY customers.&lt;/p></wd:Description>
                  <wd:Course_Number>00170024CA</wd:Course_Number>
                  <wd:Topic_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9d1f49654c8310154e4430e071ef0000</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Topic">Customer Service and Selling Skills - CAN</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Topic_Reference>
                  <wd:Language_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da5948c0446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="User_Language_ID">en_CA</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Language_Reference>
                  <wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>4</wd:Minimum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                  <wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>10</wd:Maximum_Enrollment_Capacity>
                  <wd:Waitlist_Capacity>0</wd:Waitlist_Capacity>
                  <wd:Unlimited_Capacity>0</wd:Unlimited_Capacity>
                  <wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                      <wd:Pricing_Enabled>0</wd:Pricing_Enabled>
                      <wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>0</wd:Price_in_Training_Credits>
                  </wd:Learning_Pricing_Data>
                  <wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f31be4fd5caa10001d7c6231be3b4927</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Time_Unit_ID">MINUTES</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Time_Value_Reference>
                  <wd:Total_Course_Duration>900</wd:Total_Course_Duration>
                  <wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>0</wd:Enable_Auto_Enrollment_from_Waitlist>
                  <wd:Legacy_Course>1</wd:Legacy_Course>
                  <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5cfa198ca0000</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">718700459</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                  <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5c99611170000</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">713400041</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                  <wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10124df5c72adbc60000</wd:ID>
                      <wd:ID wd:type="Learning_Instructor_ID">702300581</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Allowed_Instructor_Reference>
                  <wd:All_Locations>0</wd:All_Locations>
                  <wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>1</wd:Exclude_from_Recommendations>
                  <wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>0</wd:Exclude_from_Search_and_Browse>
                  <wd:Disable_Express_Interest>1</wd:Disable_Express_Interest>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>1</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 1</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>2</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 2</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>3</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 3</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>4</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 4</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>5</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Title>Session 5</wd:Title>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>1</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Attendance>
                          <wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>0</wd:Webinar_Lesson_Unit_Track_Grades>
                      </wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>6</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Media_Reference>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="WID">88388986cbbf10128d2c770c4c2b0003</wd:ID>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">MEDIA-6-4222</wd:ID>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">MEDIA-6-4222</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Media_Reference>
                          <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Log in Instructions (Adobe Connect - Designer 4_DesignBasics) (updated May 2022)</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                          <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                      </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                  <wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
                      <wd:Lesson_Order>7</wd:Lesson_Order>
                      <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>0</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>
                      <wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                          <wd:Media_Reference>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="WID">358e28e73d5d1010910342e9c79a0000</wd:ID>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="Media_ID">cninv000000000019226.zip</wd:ID>
                              <wd:ID wd:type="Workdrive_Item_ID">cninv000000000019226.zip</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Media_Reference>
                          <wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>Course Evaluation - vILT (L1)</wd:Learning_Course_Lesson_Title>
                          <wd:Provide_Course_Grade>0</wd:Provide_Course_Grade>
                      </wd:Media_Lesson_Data>
                  </wd:Course_Lesson_Data>
              </wd:Learning_Course_Data>
          </wd:Learning_Course>
                    </AllCourses>
       <Offerings>
        <Offering>
            <Lesson>
                <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
                <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
                <Min-Seats>10</Min-Seats>
                <Max-Seats>20</Max-Seats>
                <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
                <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 1</Title>
                <Start-Date>11/28/2022</Start-Date>
                <Start-Time>04:00PM</Start-Time>
                <End-Date>11/28/2022</End-Date>
                <End-Time>07:00PM</End-Time>
                <Facilitator-LDAP>AXH4006</Facilitator-LDAP>
                <Location/>
                <Room/>
                <Language>en_US</Language>
                <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
            </Lesson>
            <Lesson>
                <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
                <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
                <Min-Seats>10</Min-Seats>
                <Max-Seats>20</Max-Seats>
                <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
                <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 3</Title>
                <Start-Date>12/05/2022</Start-Date>
                <Start-Time>04:00PM</Start-Time>
                <End-Date>12/05/2022</End-Date>
                <End-Time>07:00PM</End-Time>
                <Facilitator-LDAP>AXH4006</Facilitator-LDAP>
                <Location/>
                <Room/>
                <Language>en_US</Language>
                <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
            </Lesson>
            <Lesson>
                <Offering-ID>C2212001 DL 3Wks Mon 4pm-7pm EASTERN</Offering-ID>
                <Course-Number>00151744</Course-Number>
                <Min-Seats>10</Min-Seats>
                <Max-Seats>20</Max-Seats>
                <Webinar>Y</Webinar>
                <Title>Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 5</Title>
                <Start-Date>12/12/2022</Start-Date>
                <Start-Time>04:00PM</Start-Time>
                <End-Date>12/12/2022</End-Date>
                <End-Time>07:00PM</End-Time>
                <Facilitator-LDAP>AXH4006</Facilitator-LDAP>
                <Location/>
                <Room/>
                <Language>en_US</Language>
                <Webinar-URL>https://hdu.adobeconnect.com</Webinar-URL>
            </Lesson>
        </Offering>
         
            </Offerings>
</FileAndCourses>
```

Expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfferingsWithCourse>
    <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 2</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 4</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 6</Error>
</OfferingsWithCourse>
```

but getting this output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfferingsWithCourse>
   <Error>No offering for 00170024CA title Session 1</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00170024CA title Session 2</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00170024CA title Session 3</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00170024CA title Session 4</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00170024CA title Session 5</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 2</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 4</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 6</Error>
</OfferingsWithCourse>
```

I want have validate only the input file course number 00151744 not the courses on Source data ,can you please help me?

Comment: Does the posted XSLT at least output the result you need without relying on streaming? Or which is the output you are looking for? Your posted sample input seems to have a single `wd:Learning_Course` element, so when you do e.g. `fold-left(wd:Learning_Course/copy-of()` it is not clear what kind of data accumulation you want to perform.

Comment: And what is the check you want to perform for validation, that any `Title` in `Offerings/Offering/Lesson` has a matching `wd:Title` in the `wd:Course_Lesson_Data`? That seems to be the case for the provided sample data. Or do you need to check that any `wd:Title` in `wd:Course_Lesson_Data` has a matching `Lesson` with that `Title`?

Comment: The posted code gives errors about a variable `LearningCourseMap` in two places where you mistyped or copied the variable names `LearningCoursesMap`. After correcting that, the  `for-each` over a boolean doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the task is to find for any `Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Title` a matching `wd:LearningCourse` based on the `Course-Number`/`wd:ID` and then to compare `Title` and `wd:Course_Lesson_Data`'s `wd:Title` then here is an approach using streaming:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="learning-course-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:ID/text()" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="webinars" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data/wd:Title/text()" 
      select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
              return
                if (map:contains($value, $id))
                then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
                else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="classroom-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Lesson_Data/wd:Title/text()" 
      select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
              return
                if (map:contains($value, $id))
                then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
                else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all" streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/FileAndCourses">
    <OfferingsWithCourse>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Offerings/Offering"/>
    </OfferingsWithCourse>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="Offering/Lesson">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="grounded"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="grounded" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson[Webinar = 'Y'][let $webinars := accumulator-before('webinars') return if (map:contains($webinars, Course-Number)) then not(Title = $webinars(Course-Number)) else false()]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      <Error>
          <xsl:text>No intructor-led webinar lesson found in course with title: </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
          <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
      </Error>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson[Webinar = 'N'][let $lessons := accumulator-before('classroom-lessons') return if (map:contains($lessons, Course-Number)) then not(Title = $lessons(Course-Number)) else false()]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <Error>
            <xsl:text>No intructor-led classrom lesson found in course with title: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
            <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
        </Error>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="grounded" match="Lesson[Webinar = 'Y'][not(map:contains(accumulator-before('webinars'), Course-Number))] | Lesson[Webinar = 'N'][not(map:contains(accumulator-before('classroom-lessons'), Course-Number))]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <Error>
            <xsl:text>Unable to find active course </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Course-Number"/>
            <xsl:text> in Workday. </xsl:text>
        </Error>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The other way around, to check whether there are offerings for given `wd:Course_Lesson_Data` would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="learning-course-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:ID/text()" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="lesson-mandatory" as="xs:boolean?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data" select="false()"/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory/text()" select=". = 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="webinars" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Webinar_Lesson_Data[accumulator-before('lesson-mandatory')]/wd:Title/text()" 
      select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
              return
                if (map:contains($value, $id))
                then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
                else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="classroom-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="AllCourses/wd:Learning_Course/wd:Learning_Course_Data/wd:Course_Lesson_Data/wd:Instructor_Led_Lesson_Data[accumulator-before('lesson-mandatory')]/wd:Title/text()" 
      select="let $id := accumulator-before('learning-course-id')
              return
                if (map:contains($value, $id))
                then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
                else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="offered-lesson-id" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Course-Number/text()" select="string()"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:accumulator name="offered-lessons" as="map(xs:string, xs:string*)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Offerings/Offering/Lesson/Title/text()" 
      select="let $id := accumulator-before('offered-lesson-id')
              return
                if (map:contains($value, $id))
                then map:put($value, $id, ($value($id), string()))
                else map:put($value, $id, string())"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all" streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/FileAndCourses" expand-text="yes">
    <OfferingsWithCourse>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:variable name="webinars" select="accumulator-after('webinars')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="offered-lessons" select="accumulator-after('offered-lessons')"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="map:keys(accumulator-after('webinars'))">
        <xsl:variable name="webinar-id" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$webinars(.)[not(. = $offered-lessons($webinar-id))]">
          <Error>No offering for {$webinar-id} title {.}</Error>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </OfferingsWithCourse>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For your sample data, this outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfferingsWithCourse>
   <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 2</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 4</Error>
   <Error>No offering for 00151744 title Launch Class Link - HDU_VILT01 - 6</Error>
</OfferingsWithCourse>
```

For your latest edit with input/output sample the wanted output is achieved by changing the last template (in the second XSLT above) to

```
  <xsl:template match="/FileAndCourses" expand-text="yes">
    <OfferingsWithCourse>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:variable name="webinars" select="accumulator-after('webinars')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="offered-lessons" select="accumulator-after('offered-lessons')"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="map:keys(accumulator-after('webinars'))[. = map:keys($offered-lessons)]">
        <xsl:variable name="webinar-id" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$webinars(.)[not(. = $offered-lessons($webinar-id))]">
          <Error>No offering for {$webinar-id} title {.}</Error>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </OfferingsWithCourse>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your help but i need a extra validation which will match the count also

Comment: Title in Offerings/Offering/Lesson has a matching wd:Title in the wd:Course_Lesson_Data which is a required course lesson data <wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory>1</wd:Make_Lesson_Mandatory> and also the count matches .In this example the count is not matching so an validation should be placed. can you help me with that

Comment: Can you help me with this validation in my xslt ,that will be useful.

Comment: @ChrisTucker2016, consider to edit your question and to show the wanted result for the posted input sample. I don't see any attempt in your code nor your text to use `Make_Lesson_Mandatory`, nor seems there to be any "count" field. If "count" means using the XPath `count` function then you need to explain which elements you want/need to count and how that is supposed to fit in with streaming. Do you have a non-streaming solution that works on small dataset but fails for your complete dataset due to memory limitations?

Comment: @ChrisTucker2016, I edited the answer to provide a second, streamable sample that outputs the `wd:Course_Lesson_Data` for which there is no matching `Offering/Lesson`.

Comment: If the course in input file are not matching to the course in course lesson data then we put the below syntax , but some syntax issue.

Comment: @ChrisTucker2016, consider to edit your question and show the exact result you want to produce with streaming XSLT for the input sample you have posted.

Comment: I have edited my xslt  that I was  attempting . It is  No matching required lesson there is some syntax issues so if the input file has no Offering/Lesson/title  or missing title from wd:Course_Lesson_Data then the validation should be shown.

Comment: Good luck with your code, but changing the code to even make it even more complicated and convoluted without telling us what result you want and which error you get nor whether your code at least does what you want without using streaming is not going to help.

Comment: Hi Martin , I need the same validation you did in your second xslt . If you check my code I getting some sytax errors . Kindly help me with same validaton in my code

Comment: In the second xslt in the source there are 100 course id and in the file there are only 5 course id . It should validate only the 5 but it is validation for all the 100 courses. can you help me with that

Comment: @ChrisTucker2016, I repeat: consider to edit your question and show the exact result you want to produce with streaming XSLT for the input sample you have posted. Better yet, edit the sample to make it minimal but complete and representative for the kind of input sample, then also show the wanted complete result you need.

Comment: Hi Martin ,I updated the source code xml  can you please help me ?

Comment: @ChrisTucker2016, I am trying to figure what you want to achieve and trying to help you achieve that. Is that requirement about `00151744` (e.g. "I want have validate only the input file course number 00151744") something that has to be inferred from the input sample or could you/would you want to pass that particular `Course-Number` as a parameter to the stylesheet?

Comment: can we pass both Course-Number and offered-lessons . any help on that

Comment: @ChrisTucker2016, take your time to try to adapt the answer for which you stated "It works" to your complete and final needs or the various requirements you might have; if you find you get stuck trying to implement one particular requirement then ask a new question with the necessary details (minimal but complete and representative samples of XML, XSLT, output you want, output or error you get, explanation of what you want to achieve and how it fails).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this might be to use streaming to delete all the data that isn't relevant to the problem, and then use a non-streaming conventional stylesheet to test the join conditions.